# Null on CompositionSubscription in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

Why Do i keep getting an NPE on this compositeSubscription, whereever I put it in the fragment.

```
    public CompositeSubscription subscriptions;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    }


        @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    subscriptions//
            .add(bindFragment(getActivity(), rxBus.toObserverable())//
                    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object event) {
                            if (event instanceof Events.LocationUpdate) {
                                Log.v(TAG,"RXBUS CHANNEL 4!!!!");
                                Log.v(TAG, event.toString());

                            }
                        }
                    }));
}
```

I put the subscription in onResume and the same error happens.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tv.loqoo.screen/com.loqooapps.Startup.Startup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.loqooapps.Fragments.LoQooTV.FragLoQooTVScreenRegistration.onStart(FragLoQooTVScreenRegistration.java:297)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1734)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1861)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5291)
```

Comment: What is line number `297` in FragLoQooTVScreenRegistration?

Comment: line 297 ---> subscriptions//

Comment: rxBus is null, or bindFragment is returning null (which might be the default if you supply it a null observable from rxBus.toObservable).

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/app/AppObservable.java) you'd be seeing an NPE inside the RxAndroid library if `rxBus.toObservable()` was returning null, therefore it appears likely that `rxBus` is null at that time.